# Moodle 2.5 How to search/compare registered Moodle users to my data and add them in bulk on course page?

Tags: php, moodle

I need to loop all Moodle registered users and get their usernames, in order to compare their values with the data I extracted from https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year=2013&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p=1&tp=s&md=3&rs=8145&it=1030123459

The data that I want is the values inside Identificador.

The Requires:

```
require_once('../../config.php');
require_once('../../lib/accesslib.php');
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/adminlib.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/'.$CFG->admin.'/user/lib.php');
require_once('lib.php');
require_login(); 

if (!isset($SESSION->bulk_users)) {
$SESSION->bulk_users = array();
}

function buildURL($year, $period, $typeperiod,$course)
{
return 'https://clip.unl.pt/sprs?lg=pt&year='.$year.'&uo=97747&srv=rsu&p='.$period.'&tp='.$typeperiod.'&md=3&rs='.$course.'&it=1030123459';
}
function doRequest_with_FileGetContents($url)
{
return file_get_contents($url);
}
```

This is getting me the values inside Identificador tags

```
function processXML($xmlContent){
    $xmlObj= new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);
    foreach($xmlObj->unidade_curricular->inscritos->aluno as $aluno){
        $result= $aluno->identificador."<br/>";
   return $result;
}
```

This gets me all Moodle users

```
function getallUsers(){
global $DB;
$users= $DB->get_records('user');
foreach($users as $user){
    $allusers= $user->username."<br/>";
return $allusers;
}
}
```

Test values:

```
$year='2013';
$period='1';
$typeperiod='s';
$course='8145';
```

I need to compare their usernames with the values inside Identificador. Only the matchable ( on Moodle) will be enrolled,in bulk, on Moodle course page, without any sort of form.

I've tried to build the idea, but not sure if i'm heading on the right track.

```
$url=buildURL($year,$period,$typeperiod,$course);
$content_b=doRequest_with_FileGetContents($url);

$results = array();
$allUsers= array();
$allUsers= getallUsers(); //getting all users on Moodle
$dataClip= array();
$dataClip= processXML($content_b);  //getting all identificadores from xml file ?
$courseid= required_param('id', PARAM_INT); 
$context= get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $courseid);//Getting students who are already enrolled                                                     
$students= get_role_users(5,$context);
// comparing usernames(identificador values) between Clip and Moodle
if(is_array($dataClip)){ //eliminates warnings of Invalid Argument in foreach
foreach($dataClip as $newdata){
    $duplicate=false;
    if(is_array($allUsers)){
    foreach($allUsers as $dataMoodle){
        // if there is a match
        if($newdata===$dataMoodle){
            // if student not enrolled yet on moodle course page.
           if(!$students){
        $duplicate=false;
        $temp_object= clone $dataMoodle;
        $results= $temp_object;
        /*
         * some code from user_bulk.php
         */
            foreach($results as $userid) {
                if ($userid == -1) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!isset($SESSION->bulk_users[$userid])) {
                    $SESSION->bulk_users[$userid] = $userid;
                }
            }           
    }
    // if there is a match and student already enrolled on moodle course page
        $duplicate=true;
        continue;
    }
    //no match. student not on moodle
    $duplicate= false;
    continue;

     }
}
}

}
//after processing redirects back to course page
$urltogo = new moodle_url('/course/view.php', array('id'=>$courseid));
redirect($urltogo);
```

And this doesn't work. I have developer mode On and no errors/warnings. And no enrolled students neither.

Comment: Does `codigo` refer to the moodle's userid?

Comment: @franzlorenzon No. codigo under **unidade_curricular** means the course id. codigo under **aluno** means the enrolled student's id on the course, on my campus Information System( CLIP).

Comment: You could solve the problem in two ways. Directly querying the moodle database (you can also export the users list using the web interface...), or by using web services (or even a combination of both). For the web services part, you could use the functions `core_course_get_courses`, `core_enrol_get_enrolled_users` and `enrol_manual_enrol_users`)

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to display all the users in the link above :)

Comment: @franzlorenzon I see. Which option you think it would be the best, in processing time? Because after the script ends, i want to redirect again to the course page. Which option would take longer?

Comment: How many users do you have? do users have a course in which they are certainly already enrolled?

Comment: @franzlorenzon My campus has around 6k students. The true enrollment on a course is provided by CLIP( campus system). For example, in the link I posted, let's say there are 320 students enrolled on that course. And 20 of them are not registered on Moodle yet. The teacher would click the item at Course Admin Block, and add to the course page, the 300 who are registered on Moodle. Meanwhile, another 5 students register on Moodle. Another click, add those 5.
However, this means i would have to compare the usernames with the entirety of Moodle's database, to get a match. The load would be heavy?

Comment: 6k records don't sound too much to me. I'll try to code something in the next days:)

Comment: @franzlorenzon Ok, much obliged. I found the 6 k number on a pdf dating 2004. I don't know if currently there are more students, but wouldn't probably surpass 7, 8k.

Comment: @franzlorenzon I found out the current number of active students on my campus. It is 12.4 k. That number ascends to 24 k if we count total users, because apparently they have been storing student's usernames since 2004.